# What is the difference between the various documents that are part of an application?

Tags: application, statement-of-purpose, terminology, application-cover-letter

I am applying to serveral undergraduate research programs this summer. Each of them ask for certain documents including:

- CV
- personal statement
- statement of interest
- cover form
- cover letter
- research statement
- statement of purpose

I understand what a CV is now, but is a cover form the same thing as a cover letter? Can these documents be generic? Is there a difference between statement of interest and statement of purpose? Is there somewhere I can find examples of these so I know what the difference is?

Comment: Don't they give additional instructions as to what should be included in each document?

Comment: Related: [Unclear terms: Statement of Purpose, Academic Statement and Personal Statement](http://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/34775/unclear-terms-statement-of-purpose-academic-statement-and-personal-statement)

Comment: @ff524 They do not. All the say is "submit the following" and then go on to list what documents each require.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I thought I would come back and answer my own question. The cover form was a special form that that program wanted me to fill out, while a cover letter was just that.

The difference between the personal statement, statement of interest, and research statement was miniscule. I just cut out some of my life from the research statement.